# Always Same Custom Error Message - VBA Word 64bit

Tags: vba, ms-word, 64-bit, word-2016

I am creating a program in VBA for Word 2016 64bit.

If someone inputs letter into a TextBox formatted for integers, it shows a error message.

How can I make it not allow the user to input anything other than an integer? Can I have it check when the user clicks the Submit button? Here is an example of the code of one TextBox:

```
Private Sub CurrentRate_AfterUpdate()
    If CurrentRate.Text - CurrentRate.Text > 0 Then
        CurrentRate.Value = Format(CurrentRate.Value, "Percent")

    Else
        CurrentRate.Text = CurrentRate.Text / 100
        CurrentRate.Value = Format(CurrentRate.Value, "Percent")
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically it is taking the value of `currentRate` and doing a math operating and then formatting it as a percent. If it is not an integer it can not do the math or format it as a percent which is the cause of the error.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The first thing is not to attempt to subtract, or divide, Text values. You need to check that they are numbers first. You also haven't presented any attempt to provide a MsgBox? Or what other means do you intend to use to provide messages?

Comment: @brendan, you are contradicting yourself. you say that the users are not tech savvy. then you want to build an app that tells the user absolutely nothing about the error that they just made. maybe you should have the program flash a big red X on the screen. you are just asking for someone to come up to your boss and say _"hey, I can fix that horrible interface that Brendan could not be bothered to design properly"_

Comment: @jsotola I just rewrote the question. I hope it is better! If you think it is and you want to could you please upvote it! Thanks! I already figured it out but wanted to make it better in case someone else needs help!

Comment: @AndyG Please look at the above comment.

Comment: Your question and answer remain flawed because you are still attempting to subtract text. Subtracting is not a valid operation for strings. It is unfortunate that VBA does not flag this as an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Going off of what Andy G said, I found I should check if the value is a number, if it is do the formula, if it is not do a message box.

```
Private Sub CurrentRate_AfterUpdate()
    If IsNumeric(CurrentRate.Text) Then

        If CurrentRate.Text - CurrentRate.Text > 0 Then
            CurrentRate.Value = Format(CurrentRate.Value, "Percent")

        Else
            CurrentRate.Text = CurrentRate.Text / 100
            CurrentRate.Value = Format(CurrentRate.Value, "Percent")
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again")
        CurrentRate.Text = ""

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are still subtracting and dividing .Text. Use a variable to store the number, once you've confirmed that it is a number.

Comment: It checks if it is a number and if it is it will divide. Otherwise it wont.

Comment: `IsNumeric("4.5%")` returns `False`. This solution doesn't round-trip very well.

Comment: @Brendan, how do you know that it did not divide?

Comment: Because it puts it into a text box and I looked at the textbox. This snippet is not all my code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug  I just rewrote the question. I hope it is better! If you think it is and you want to could you please upvote it! Thanks! I already figured it out but wanted to make it better in case someone else needs help!

Comment: i downvoted your answer so anybody else that tries to use it, will check it first.   .... it contains bad logic. .... `CurrentRate.Text - CurrentRate.Text > 0` will always be `false` ... you have a chunk of useless code that never gets executed

Comment: Why is that always false?

Comment: because 0>0 is always false

Comment: How about `CurrentRate.Text < 1`

Comment: is that the whole statement ? or is it part of `if CurrentRate.Text - CurrentRate.Text < 1 then` ?

Comment: The whole line would be `If CurrentRate.Text < 1 Then` checking if `CurrentRate.Text` is less than 1.

Comment: you are using flawed logic in your program.  you are assuming (i think) that an entry of, for example .5 is 50%. .... why is it not .5% ?  also your program has a problem with unintended execution. example ... enter `123` in text box .... program evaluates the number and replaces `123` in text box with `123.00%` .... since the program is executed when the text box is updated, it executes again .... evaluates `123.00%` .... which is not numeric, because of the text character "%" .... well, you know the rest of the story

Comment: Ok I will fix it